# Generating Dynamic Rotation

Tags: c#, rotation, unity-game-engine

I currently have a script which makes a GameObject move relative to another GameObject like shown in the .gif below.

[image: Dynamic Movement *Only*]

What I still haven't figured out is how to make the same GameObject **rotate** relative to the position of the other GameObject in a way that it always ends up with the original rotation like shown in the following image:

[image: Dynamic Rotation]

So, now that I have "Dynamic Movement" (as in the .gif), how can I create "Dynamic Rotation" (as in the image)?

I do not have the experience to accomplish such a task and searching the Web did not help either, so I would really appreciate a ready-to-deploy script. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: how many times do you want to rotate it? only 1 (360 degree) or 2 tours(720 degree) or it depends on distance?

Comment: I want to rotate 360 degrees for now, but I want the option to be easily able to adjust this later.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you just want to make sure that object flips given number of time in the air while in flight. You can use something like this:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class RotaionManager : MonoBehaviour {

    // Motion start point
    public Transform origin;
    // Motion end point
    public Transform destination;

    // Start and en anle - 360 for single full rotation
    public float startAngle = 0;
    public float endAngle = 360;

    void Update () {

        // Distance to origin
        var dstOrigin = Vector3.Distance(origin.position, transform.position);
        // Distance to destination
        var dstDestination = Vector3.Distance(destination.position, transform.position);
        // Parameter
        float t = (dstDestination + dstOrigin == 0 ? 0 : (dstOrigin / (dstDestination + dstOrigin) ) );
        // The angle at current t
        float angle = Mathf.Lerp(startAngle, endAngle, t);

        // Rotate the object by the angle, then make sure it also faces destination
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(destination.position - origin.position) * Quaternion.Euler(angle, 0, 0);

    }
}
```

Simply linear interpolation of rotation angle, based on distances to start and end point. You can control how many times the object rotates by start and end angles. Look at rotation is used so that in addition to rotation around its own axis, the object will also face general direction of destination.

Have a look at sample project:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/g00srsjlqjx1jcz/RotationProj.zip?dl=0

**EDIT**

It may be better to use distance from object projection on source-destination vector instead of raw distance, it looks better on steep paths. The update function will look like this:

```
void Update () {

    // Projection of object on line between origin and destination
    var projection = Vector3.Project(transform.position - origin.position, origin.position - destination.position) + origin.position;
    // Distance to origin
    var dstOrigin = Vector3.Distance(origin.position, projection);
    // Distance to destination
    var dstDestination = Vector3.Distance(destination.position, projection);
    // Parameter
    float t = (dstDestination + dstOrigin == 0 ? 0 : (dstOrigin / (dstDestination + dstOrigin) ) );
    // The angle at current t
    float angle = Mathf.Lerp(startAngle, endAngle, t);

    // Rotate the object by the angle, then make sure it also faces destination
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(destination.position - origin.position) * Quaternion.Euler(angle, 0, 0);

}
```

I also updated the sample project

**EDIT**

Another way to do it which may look better, may be to ignore **Y** coordinates of start and end points, and do the projection. It looks a little better in some corner cases. The code will look this way:

```
void Update () {

    Vector3 op = origin.position; op.y = 0;
    Vector3 dp = destination.position; dp.y = 0;
    // Projection of object on line between origin and destination
    var projection = Vector3.Project(transform.position - origin.position, op - dp) + op;
    // Distance to origin
    var dstOrigin = Vector3.Distance(op, projection);
    // Distance to destination
    var dstDestination = Vector3.Distance(dp, projection);
    // Parameter
    float t = (dstDestination + dstOrigin == 0 ? 0 : (dstOrigin / (dstDestination + dstOrigin) ) );
    // The angle at current t
    float angle = Mathf.Lerp(startAngle, endAngle, t);

    // Rotate the object by the angle, then make sure it also faces destination
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dp - op) * Quaternion.Euler(angle, 0, 0);

}
```

Comment: Excellent answer. But, your scripts only seem to work properly on the X and Z axis but not on the Y axis. Check [this](http://s17.postimg.org/70dgr072l/GIF.gif) out.

Comment: After looking at this I realized the projection point is not computed correctly, which makes the rotation not full when origin and destination are not the same height. Updated the answer with the correct way. I also updated the sample project to illustrate the case when origin or destination move on Y axis.

Comment: With the latest edit, Cube isn't rotating properly at certain positions. Check [this](http://s13.postimg.org/dj9h2c7x3/GIF2.gif) out.

Comment: The whole algorithm is based on giving good approximation to `t` value. This value represents the portion of the path the object already traveled relative to total path length. Here I gave 2 ways to approximate this, bay raw distance or by projection on source-destination vector. I don't see a better way to approximate this in a generic way. A better approximation is possible, but for this you have to specify exactly what algorithm you use to move your objects, the solution depends on it, so if you post the code it will be able to help.

Comment: Giving it a little more thought, there is another good approximation, I updated the answer. Did not update the project though (dropbox under maintenance now). Hope this helps.

Comment: There's an issue with the latest edit of your script. The Cube starts and ends with the wrong rotation. See [here](http://s14.postimg.org/5owsicxvz/GIF3.gif).

Comment: Damn it, I knew I missed somehing. The last line should be `transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(dp - op) * Quaternion.Euler(angle, 0, 0);`. I also updated the project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @YuraNudelman But, your scripts do not cooperate very well with the .GIF's script which I added in the question. Can you fix this?

Comment: @YuraNudelman Your script works properly now! :) But, in order to receive +200 reputation, you'll have to reply to _Jean Mauz_ (the OP).

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I but I fail to see how why the script I supplied would not work with Jumper script - it  is very generic. You should simply attach the RotaionManager script to the same game object powered by your Jumper script, very simple. As far as I checked it worked like charm.

Comment: Can you please upload your Unity project so we can see? Thank you very much.

Comment: @YuraNudelman There's an issue. When the Cube reaches the destination, its rotation is not 360. See [here](http://s17.postimg.org/hu6igpysv/rotation.png). Try it on your own and you'll see. This results in a slippery slope everytime `RestartMotion()` is called. The more it's called the more the rotation is wrong. If it's exacly 360, we'll have no problems.

Comment: @YuraNudelman If you remove `RestartMotion();` from `private IEnumerator jumpAndFollow(GameObject goToJumpTo, float timeToJump)` you'll see that the final rotation is not 360.

Comment: The reason why final rotation is not exactly 360 is because Jumper final position is not exactly destination (it is based on frame rate and will always have inaccuracies). Rotation is computed based on position. But you are wrong assuming this can be accumulated from run to run - rotation is computed individually for each moment in time based only on position and not on previous rotation values. After a billion runs, at the same point of the jump arc it will be the same rotation.

Comment: @YuraNudelman Yes, you're right. But can you make it not based on frame rate and thus, the final rotation would be 360? Is that even possible? Unfortunately, I need the final rotation to be exactly 360 for my game to work properly...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97322/discussion-between-yura-nudelman-and-jamie-wright).

Answer (score 0):

One possibility that has helped me in similar situations is [`transform.LookAt`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) function.  This allows you to always face your target.  You would put something like `transform.LookAt(target.transform)` in your `Update` method and you would always be facing your target.  Once you reach your target you may want to set it to a constant value as there might be some issues with weird rotations if you are not exactly at the same location as your target.

Comment: Open bounty worth +200 reputation started for a ready-to-deploy script!

Answer (score 0):

- I assume there is a thrower, rock, and target in your game.  Thrower
  throws the rock to the target and rock should turn total 360 degree.

  ```
  private float mag = 0 ;//will be total distance
  private Vector3 throwerPos ;
  private Boolean isThrown = false;// you have to set this true whenever you throw a rock.

  void Update()
  {
   .
   .
   if(isThrown)
   {
    mag = (target.position -thrower.position).magnitude;//get distance whenever you throw it.
    throwerPos = thrower.position;
    rotateIt();
   }
  } 

  void rotateIt()
  {
   float currMag = (rock.position - throwerPos).magnitute ;//get current distance between rock and thrower and rotate it depends on distance at the throwing time
       angle= Mathf.MoveTowards(0,360,currMag / mag);
       rock.getComponent<Transform>().eulerAngles = new Vector3(
       rock.getComponent<Transform>().eulerAngles.x,
       rock.getComponent<Transform>().eulerAngles.y,
       angle);
      if(angle == 360)
      {
        rock.getComponent<Transform>().eulerAngles.z=0;
        isThrown = false;
      }
  }
  ```

  I did not execute this code, this may not work. This is just an idea. There are a lot of ways to achieve this I think.

Comment: Rock. Just use getcomponent... instead rock.getcom.. this is a pseudo code. You need to configure it for your game.